# Problems with load data in CollectionViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I ve a problem with my collectionViewController and their data load...

I trying load a external JSON file...

The first problems is when the app load that CollectionViewController only shows the collection Cell , without images and texts...

Initial load

[image]

When the JSON is loaded and I scrolling screen their appears like that:

After loaded JSON and scrolling screen

[image]

What could be the solution, the CollectionViewController showed is the first to show so Isn't possible charge that CollectionViewController in other CollectionViewController,
 thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call `[YourCollectionView reloadData]` to rebind the UIcollectionview after JSON loaded

Good Luck

Comment: Ankur thx a lot, your answer works fine.. but the loading of Json is very longer and cells are empty until Json is loaded, you know any solution for that?

Comment: u can show a loading indicator https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD until the JSON loaded

Comment: Thx Mustafa! Your first answer, runs fine!

Answer (score 0):

Besides of an Activity Indicator, you could also add a placeholder image in the CollectionViewCell(for example the logo of your app) while the JSON is loaded. In this downloader framework: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage you have a method that does exactly this: `setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder`. Otherwise, you could set the placeholder image manually with a success/failure [block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html).